# How can I create build and deployment automation package which can include PowerApp, MS Flow and SharePoint list?

Tags: powerapp, ms-flow

We have created a application on PowerApp and Microsoft flow by using the SharePoint list and, want to build and deployment automation package as specified in the link for Dynamics CRM:

https://devkeydet.blog/2018/04/10/build-and-deployment-automation-of-a-model-driven-powerapp-using-vsts/comment-page-1/?unapproved=55&moderation-hash=45c2ce1b950351e67c315e1abf1a6877#comment-55